# problem with insert in laravel with auth module

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a newbie in Laravel, just starting to mess around with the auth module, I generated the basic stuff and added some fields in the migration, but after making changes in the view, model and registration controller the registration doesn't work, I tried using var_dump but it doesn't show anything (or at least I don't know exactly where to put it)

Here is my code:

**User**

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'surname', 'business_name','user_document','user_document','nit','email','password','business_base_url','location','address','city','currency','phone1','phone2','payment_platform','active_payment','password','status','active',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function Store_details(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Store_details');
    }
}
```

**RegisterController**

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    
    class RegisterController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Register Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
        | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
        | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
        |
        */
    
        use RegistersUsers;
    
        /**
         * Where to redirect users after registration.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    
        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest');
        }
    
        /**
         * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
         *
         * @param  array  $data
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
         */
        protected function validator(array $data){
    
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'business_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
                'user_document' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
                'nit' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
                'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'max:12','confirmed'],
                'business_base_url' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5','max:12','unique:users'],
                'location' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'max:12','confirmed'],
                'address' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10','max:20', 'confirmed'],
                'city' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:20','confirmed'],
                'currency' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:3','confirmed'],
                'phone1' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5','max:10','confirmed'],
                'phone2' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5','max:10', 'confirmed'],
                'payment_platform' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5','max:10', 'confirmed'],
                'active_payment' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1','max:1', 'confirmed'],
                'status' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1','max:1', 'confirmed'],
                'active' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1','max:1', 'confirmed'],
            ]);
        }
    
        
    
        /**
         * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
         *
         * @param  array  $data
         * @return \App\User
         */
        protected function create(array $data){
    
            return User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'surname' => $data['surname'],
                'user_document' => $data['user_document'],
                'business_name' => $data['business_name'],
                'business_base_url' => $data['business_base_url'],
                'nit' => $data['nit'],
                'location' => $data['location'],
                'address' => $data['address'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'city' => $data['city'],
                'currency' => $data['currency'],
                'phone1' => $data['phone1'],
                'phone2' => $data['phone2'],
                'payment_platform' => $data['payment_platform'],
                'active_payment' => $data['active_payment'],
                'status' => $data['status'],
                'active' => $data['active'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**register.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Registro') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nombre') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="surname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Apellido') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="surname" type="text" class="form-control @error('surname') is-invalid @enderror" name="surname" value="{{ old('surname') }}" required autocomplete="surname" autofocus>

                                @error('surname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="user_document" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Documento') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="user_document" type="text" class="form-control @error('user_document') is-invalid @enderror" name="user_document" value="{{ old('user_document') }}" required autocomplete="user_document" autofocus>

                                @error('user_document')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="nit" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nombre del negocio') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="business_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('business_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="business_name" value="{{ old('business_name') }}" required autocomplete="business_name" autofocus>

                                @error('user_document')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="business_base_url" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Url del negocio') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="business_base_url" type="text" class="form-control @error('business_base_url') is-invalid @enderror" name="business_base_url" value="{{ old('business_base_url') }}" required autocomplete="business_name" autofocus>

                                @error('user_document')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="nit" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nit') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nit" type="text" class="form-control @error('nit') is-invalid @enderror" name="nit" value="{{ old('nit') }}" required autocomplete="nit" autofocus>

                                @error('user_document')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Contraseña') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirmar contraseña') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Registro') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I tried searching on the logs folder but I cant find anything relevant.

When I send the form it doesn't display any error, it just doesn't do anything after the submit.

I'll really appreciate if someone can explain me how to debug this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The validation in your `RegisterController` specifies fields like `phone1` and `phone2` are required but they are not present in your `register.blade.php` view and there's no way of Laravel displaying any associated validation errors as there's no corresponding `@error('phone1')` etc. So I suspect your validation is failing.

Comment: thanks! @Unflux ill check it and let you know!

Comment: @Unflux it wasnt that i removed the validation and still doesnt work

Comment: Can you update the code in your question so that we can take another look? [: